# Type Parameter T has incompatible upper bounds: Views and MessageList error

Tags: java, android, android-studio

"Type Parameter T has incompatible upper bounds: Views and MessageList", I did Invalidate Caches/Restart but still MessageList line has error.

```
 private void initViews() {
    MessageInput inputView = findViewById(R.id.input);
    MessagesList messagesList = findViewById(R.id.messagesList); // Here is the error

    inputView.setInputListener(input -> {
        //validate and send message
        sendMessage(input.toString());
        return true;
    });
    String senderId = CometChat.getLoggedInUser().getUid();

    adapter = new MessagesListAdapter<>(senderId, null);

    messagesList.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: How is `adapter` defined?

Comment: Its defined globally

Comment: @JoachimSauer tried renaming my xml file also but error still remains. MessageInput does not have any error but MessageList has .

Comment: Yes, but **how**? What does the field declaration look like?

Comment: @JoachimSauer private MessagesListAdapter<MessageWrapper> adapter; this is how I defined